# React Projekt!! Webpack 4 -> Webpack 5 == compiler error, How i can fix this bug?

Tags: reactjs, styles, semantic-ui, webpack-5

I took a Repo from an older Version an want to update this one. The repo is currently using semantic-ui after running

```
npm install  and **npm start**
```

i get some errors, about the Webpack compiler that the loaders can´t get readed.

I tried to change and update the loaders but all off it didn´t worked for me ...

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         include: [
           path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-dropzone-component/styles"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/dropzone/dist/min"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-tabs/style/"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/"),
           path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules","semantic-ui-css, semantic-min-css"),
         ],
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
       }, {
        test: /\.(ico|json)$/,
        include: /assets\/main/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
      }, {
        test: /.png$/,
        include: /assets\/(icons|images)/,
        use: ['file-loader?outputPath=icons\/&name=[name].[ext]']
      }, {
        test: /.txt$/,
        include: /assets\/text/,
        use: ['raw-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: /src/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new ESLintPlugin({extensions: ['js', 'jsx']}),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ejs')
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify")
    }
  }
};
```

Here is my packkage.json

```
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7"
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.179.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
```

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./assets/main/favicon.ico 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)


ERROR in ./assets/text/konfuzius.txt 1:5

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> Alle Dunkelheit der Welt kann das Licht einer einzigen Kerze nicht auslöschen.
| Bohre den Brunnen, ehe du Durst hast.
| Der Dumme lernt aus seinen Fehlern, der Kluge aus den Fehlern der anderen.


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-16x16.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-32x32.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-120x120.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-128x128.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-144x144.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-152x152.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-192x192.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-256x256.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/icons/logo-512x512.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/images/konfuzius.png

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./assets/images/spinner.svg

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at getHashDigest (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\node_modules\loader-utils\lib\interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Karadag\e-files-frontend\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:29:48)


ERROR in ./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css 11:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  *
|  */
> @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);/*!
|  * # Semantic UI 2.4.0 - Reset
|  * http://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/
```

Comment: Webpack 5 has many breaking changes, when you migrate from webpack 4. 

https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

Only updating may break the whole webpack. Be sure you followed all the steps. From your description it is not very clear, what exactly may have caused the error.

Comment: Thx for the advice, i read through several times, and did´nt found the information for solve this error....

Comment: Then it seems some dependency issue, which node version are u  using? Did you update it before installing the dependencies?

Comment: yes, i´m using the current version v19.0.0

Comment: after updated my Node to v19.0.0 iI installed all the dependedecies..

Comment: I think node 19 is too much, it is not a stable release. 18 is stable , but you can try with 16.16.0 verion. I would try to install node 16.16.0, you can use nvm and try to install again. 

If doesn't work, will try to have a different look myself.

Comment: Thx, I tried to use now 16.16.0 , it is still not working.. but it shows less errors :) Thanks for help i may can solve them by my own 
```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)

Comment: there is some Unexpected character as the error shows :)